# RewriteRule for query string to static URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a tag based search button linking to mydomain.com/product/search/?tag=hoodies that I want to rewrite in the browser to display as "mydomain.com/hoodies/ (but still pull the content from that original URL).

Its a purely aesthetics move, I have tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^tag=tanks
RewriteRule ^product/search/$ /tanks/ [L,QSA,NC]
```

Doesnt work for me, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+product/search/\?tag=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ product/search/?tag=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhava! I really appreciate it. I have also noticed how many times you have helped others with htaccess questions, you are a great asset to this community :) Just one small thing, how would I add a / suffix to each url so that it ends up as mydomain.com/hoodies/ (right now its missing the last "/". Thanks !

Comment: Nevermind, I added /%1/? and now it works. Last thing if I may (still relating to the OP), should I change that to a 301 redirect or leave it on 302?

Comment: Yes once verified change 302 to 301. I use 302 for testing only.

Comment: Thank you, i am completely sorted!